# Extracting the sign bit with shift

Tags: c, language-lawyer, bit-shift

Is it always defined behavior to extract the sign of a 32 bit integer this way:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int get_sign(int32_t x) {
    return (x & 0x80000000) >> 31;
}
```

Do I always get a result of `0` or `1`?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is incorrect to do this because right shifting a signed integer with a negative value is implementation-defined, as specified in the C Standard:

> **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>
> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1 / 2`<sup>`E2`</sup>. If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

You should cast `x` as `(uint32_t)` before masking and shifting.

**EDIT: Wrong answer!** I shall keep this answer here as an example of good looking, intuitive but incorrect reasoning.  As explained in the other answers, there is not right shifting of a negative value in the code posted. The type of `x & 0x80000000` is one of the signed integer or unsigned integer types depending on the implementation characteristics, but its value is always positive, either `0` or `2147483648`.  Right shifting this value is not implementation-defined, the result is always either `0` or `1`.  Whether the result is the value of the sign bit is less obvious: it is the value of the sign bit except for some very contorted corner cases, hybrid architectures quite unlikely to exist and probably non standard conforming anyway.

Comment: I would expect `(x & 0x80000000)` to be an _unsigned_ value.  `(int32_t) & unsigned_constant`  I now see your [improved & good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38507883/2410359) elsewhere

Comment: I think it is clear now that this answer does not apply under any condition. The value `(x & 0x80000000)` is always positive so no right shift  implementation-defined behavior. Recommend deletion.

Answer (score 2):

Since the answer assumes that fixed width types are available, therefore a negative zero doesn't exists<sup>1</sup>, the only correct way of extracting the sign bit is to simply check if the value is negative:

```
_Bool Sign( const int32_t a )
{
    return a < 0 ;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Fixed width types require two's complement representation, which doesn't have a negative zero.

Comment: I agree that it is a better way and I was expecting this alternative, but why do you insist on it being *the only correct way*?

Comment: @chqrlie Your other method is simply too complicated, look at the answer. I found a flaw in the first paragraph. This is a strictly better answer in this case.

Comment: you are saying that even if `int` has 32 bits, `int32_t` and `int` may be different types, so paragraph 1 has a flaw.  That's possible,  The main point is to determine the type of `0x80000000`. It can be `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long` or even `long long`.  In all these cases, the operation can be proven to be defined.  Can you provide a counter-example?

Comment: @chqrlie I've deleted my previous commend a while ago as it had a flaw.

Comment: I agree that `return a < 0;` is a better solution, the question asked is not what is the best solution, it is about the potential for an implementation-defined result.

Comment: @chqrlie Even if it is defined, it is right under the line. Also the right shift is artificially added, there is no reason whatsoever to use it. It only brings implementation defined behavior. A simple ! or != operator would prevent this. What I'm trying to say is that this is a contrived example.

Comment: I agree it is under the line.  Even proving correctness seems difficult.  `return !(x & 0x80000000);` is even harder to read and produces worse code. I came up with this question from reading this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494947/doubling-and-dividing-floating-point-values .  The code seemed incorrect at first sight...

Comment: "that fixed width types are available, therefore a (integer) negative zero doesn't exists" is certainly a very reasonable conclusion, yet not supported by C spec a AFAIK.  Unicorn platform could have both non-2's complement `int` and `-0` and `int32_t`.

Comment: @chux 6.2.6.2 2 Says: *For signed integer types... ... If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in **one** of the
following ways:.. ...Which of these applies is implementation-defined* . This seems pretty clear that only one can be chosen for signed integer types.

Comment: Proof was indeed difficult... in the end sign/magnitude provides counterexamples. So you may be right in your assessment of this method as *the only correct one*.

Comment: @chqrlie sign-magnitude can't exist with intn_t types.

Comment: The `intxx_t` are defined to use 2s complement with no padding bits, but the C Standard does not specifically exclude the possibility for `int32_t` to co-exist with sign/magnitude `int` on an exotic architecture.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes it does. Did you read my above two comments, and 6.2.6.2 p2?

Comment: @2501: I understand your argument, and I would be glad to get to the same conclusion as you do, that different integer representation cannot coexist... I guess the language of (informative) annex J.3.5 is even more explicit: *A conforming implementation is required to document its choice of behavior in each of the areas listed in this subclause. The following are implementation-defined:* *Whether signed integer types are represented using sign and magnitude, two’s complement, or ones’ complement, and whether the extraordinary value is a trap representation or an ordinary value (6.2.6.2).*

Comment: The **one** refers to 1 of 3 types.  Much like the previous paragraph use of `M` and `N`, it does not imply all signed integer types use the same 1 of 3, the same `M`, and same `N`.  Your POV is not with-out merit and this issue deserves a SO question unto itself.  Certainly would come up with a more authoritative answer then us 3.  (@chqrlie)

Comment: @chqrlie First of all that is informative. It isn't *the* standard. The text says: *A conforming implementation is required to document its **choice*** and *Whether signed integer types are represented using sign and magnitude, two’s complement, **or** ones’ complement* An implementation has to choose one.

Comment: When the dust finally settles, comparing to `0` is the better solution, but not the only correct way.

Comment: @chux I agree. Post a question, I would love to upvote it. Perhaps wait until the docs situation is resolved.

Comment: @chux Let me know if you do please. I promise not to get involved in the discussion since I'm clearly biased.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct on 1s and 2s complement architectures, but for subtile reasons:

1. for the overwhelmingly common hardware where `int` is the same type as `int32_t` and `unsigned` the same as `uint32_t`, the constant literal `0x80000000` has type `unsigned int`. The left operand of the `&` operation is converted to `unsigned int` and the result of the `&` has the same type.  The right shift is applied to an `unsigned int`, the value is either `0` or `1`, no implementation-defined behavior.

On other platforms, `0x80000000` may have a different type and the behavior might be implementation defined:

- `0x80000000` can be of type `int`, if the `int` type has more than 31 value bits. In this case, `x` is promoted to `int`, and its value is unchanged.

  1. If `int` uses 1s complement or 2s complement representation, the sign bit is replicated into the more significant bits.  The mask operation evaluates to an `int` with value `0` or `0x80000000`.  Right shifting it by `31` positions evaluates to `0` and `1` respectively, no implementation-defined behavior either.
  2. Conversely, if `int` uses sign/magnitude representation, preserving the value of `x` will effectively reset its 31st bit, moving the sign bit beyond the value bits.  The mask operation will evaluate to `0` and the result will be incorrect.
- `0x80000000` can be of type `long`, if the `int` type has fewer than 31 value bits or if `INT_MIN == -INT_MAX` and `long` has more that 31 value bits. In this case, `x` is converted to `long`, and its value is unchanged, with the same consequences as for the `int` case. For 1s or 2s complement representation of `long`, the mask operation evaluates to a positive `long` value of either `0` or `0x80000000` and right shifting it by 31 places is defined and gives either `0` or `1`, for sign/magnitude, the result should be `0` in all cases.
- `0x80000000` can be of type `unsigned long`, if the `int` type has fewer than 31 value bits and `long` has 31 value bits and uses 2s complement representation. In this case, `x` is converted to `unsigned long` keeping the sign bit intact.  The mask operation evaluates to an `unsigned long` value of either `0` or `0x80000000` and right shifting it by 31 places is defined and gives either `0` or `1`.
- lastly, `0x80000000` can be of type `long long`, if both the `int` type has fewer than 31 value bits or `INT_MIN == -INT_MAX` and `long` has 31 value bits but does not use 2s complement representation. In this case, `x` is converted to `long long`, keeping its value, with the same consequences as for the `int` case if `long long` representation is sign/magnitude.

This question was purposely contrived. The answer is you get the correct result so long as the platform does not use sign/magnitude representation. But the C Standard insists on supporting integer representations other than 2s complement, with very subtile consequences.

**EDIT:** Careful reading of section **6.2.6.2 Integer types** of the C Standard seems to exclude the possibility for different representations of signed integer types to coexist in the same implementation.  This makes the code fully defined as posted, since the very presence of type `int32_t` implies 2s complement representation for all signed integer types.

Comment: Integer promotions cannot promote to `long`.

Comment: @chux: I though so, but then I thought again and found counterexamples. sign/magnitude is absolute evil.

Comment: Yes, I was was going to mention unicorn machines with a mixture of integer representations, but I see you swept that corner too -nice.

Comment: @chux C doesn't support such architectures. See my other comment.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I always get a result of 0 or 1?

Yes.

Simple answer:
`0x80000000 >> 31` is *always* 1.
`0x00000000 >> 31` is *always* 0.

See below.

[Edit]

> Is it always defined behavior to extract the **sign** of a 32 bit integer this way

Yes, except for a corner case.

Should `0x80000000` implement as a `int/long` (this implies the type > 32 bit) *and* that signed integer type is signed-magnitude (or maybe one's complement) on a [novel machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicorn), then the conversion of `int32_t x` to that `int/long` would move the sign bit to a new bit location, rendering the `& 0x80000000` moot.

The question is open if C supports `int32_t` (which must be 2's complement) and  any of `int/long/long long` as non-2's complement.

---

`0x80000000` is a hexadecimal constant.  "The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented" C11 §6.4.4.1 5: Octal or Hexadecimal Constant: `int`, `unsigned`, `long` or `unsigned long`....  Regardless of its type, it will have a *value* of `+2,147,483,648`.

The *type* of `x & 0x80000000` will be the wider of the types of `int32_t` and the type of `0x80000000`.  If the 2 types are the same width and differ in sign-ness, it will be the unsigned one.   `INT32_MAX` is `+2,147,483,647` and less than `+2,147,483,648`, thus `0x80000000` must be a wider type (or same and unsigned) than `int32_t`.  So regardless of what type `0x80000000`, `x & 0x80000000` will be the *same* type.

It makes no difference how `int` nor `long` are implemented as 2's complement or not.

The `&` operation does not change the sign of the value of `0x80000000` as either it is an unsigned integer type or the sign bit is in a more significant position.  `x & 0x80000000` then has the  *value* of `+2,147,483,648` or `0`.

Right shift of a positive number is well defined regardless of integer type.  Right shift of negative values are implementation defined.  See C11 §6.5.7 5. `x & 0x80000000` is never a negative number.

Thus `(x & 0x80000000) >> 31` is well defined and either 0 or 1.

`return x < 0;` (which does not "Extracting the sign bit with shift" per post title) is understandable and is certainly the preferred code for most instances I can think of.  Either approach may not make any executable code difference.

Comment: Well thought and good answer to the second question, but it does matter how the signed values are represented because the conversion from `int32_t` to the type of `0x80000000` may change the 31st bit if the representation were sign/magnitude and `0x80000000` is `long` with more than 31 value bits.  In this case, the expression would compute to `0`, not the sign bit.

Comment: @chqrlie I will ponder your comment: converting a `int32_t` into a signed-magnitude wider type.

Comment: An architecture with 2s complement 32 bit `short` and sign/magnitude 64 bit `int`, `long` and `long long` would yield an incorrect result.  2501 advocates that such an architecture does not conform to the Standard.

Comment: @chqrlie Just ask  that question sometime chux.

Comment: @chqrlie Looks like we arrived at similar conclusions.  BTW: Questions: easy. Answers: a bit harder.  Good answer: harder yet.  Good questions: most difficult.

Comment: I don't believe 1s complement poses a problem: negative values are padded with ones when extended. sign/magnitude is the potential issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this expression has precisely defined semantics or not, it is not the most readable way to get the sign bit.  Here is simpler alternative:

```
int get_sign(int32_t x) {
    return x < 0;
}
```

As correctly pointed out by 2501, `int32_t` is defined to have 2s complement representation, so comparing to `0` has the same semantics as extracting the most significant bit.

Incidentally, both functions compile to the same exact code with `gcc 5.3`:

```
get_sign(int):
    movl    %edi, %eax
    shrl    $31, %eax
    ret
```